# Do higher levels of resource gathering actually grant me more resources, or just faster resources?

Tags: dice-legacy

In *Dice Legacy*, there are worker positions with a small *x* on them, which say "Result is influenced by face level."  If I put a tool face with a 2 or 3 on it in such a position, I'll get more resources.

But what does that actually mean?  Any given resource space has a limit, indicated by the big red number (18 in the picture below).

If I put a tool (3) die face on this spot, do I get 3 resources while it only takes 1 from 18?  Or does the 18 become 15, indicating that I'm not getting *more* resources, but only *faster* resources from the limited amount available?

[image: Hunting Grounds with 18 food]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from what I've seen in my own games that higher-level die faces grant **faster** resource gathering.

I put a die with a resource gathering face of level **8** on a forested patch with a value of **26**.

Then I watched.

When the die finished, I received **11** wood (**8** plus **3** bonus from research), and the patch now had a value of **15**.

So enhancing the die face for resource gathering doesn't increase the amount of resources you get from a patch; it only helps you gather those resources more quickly.

Similarly, it appears that research that increases resource gathering only helps you gather faster from the same limited amount of resources.

One conclusion from this is that you don't need to worry that you're missing out on bonus material if you gather a lot of resources early on.  Whether your die has a level of 1 or 8 on its gathering face, you'll eventually get the same amount of wood, stone, etc.  You'll just get it faster or slower.  (Of course, gathering it faster means you have to expend less food per resource for your die to recover durability.)